# Querystring generated with asp-for doesn't match that generated from Url.Action on same model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Currently redeveloping a part of the site, and I'm struggling to get some of the new asp.net features to line up with legacy code.

In particular, one of the forms has been changed to use the asp-for attribute:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <input asp-for="@this.Model.SearchFilters.Surname" class="form-control" placeholder="@(page.Labels["Surname"].Content.Term)" aria-label="@(page.Labels["Surname"].Content.Term)" />
</div>
<div class="form-group label-floating col-lg-6 col-xs-12">
    <input asp-for="@this.Model.SearchFilters.Firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="@(page.Labels["Forenames"].Content.Term)" aria-label="@(page.Labels["Forenames"].Content.Term)" />
</div>
```

This generates a querystring like so:

```
?SearchFilters.Surname=bob&SearchFilters.Firstname=tway
```

In a controller action down the line, a path back to this page is generated with `Url.Action:`

```
Url.Action(
    nameof(this.MyMethod),
    new { viewModel.SearchFilters.Firstname, viewModel.SearchFilters.Surname });
```

But that generates a querystring without the SearchFilters prefix:

```
?Surname=bob&Firstname=tway
```

Since that doesn't match the expected model, the generated Url results in a server error.

I've tried to change the Url.Action to specify the name like so:

```
Url.Action(
    nameof(this.MyMethod),
    new { SearchFilters.Firstname = viewModel.SearchFilters.Firstname, SearchFilters.Surname = viewModel.SearchFilters.Surname });
```

But this won't compile, saying it's an "Invalid anonymous type member declarator".

In an ideal world I'd like to change the Url.Action to include the prefix, but I can't work out how this is done. I'd settle for removing the prefix generated by asp-for, as I change the model if need be. Either way, how do I bring these two Querystrings into line?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a parameter name with a period by using a `RouteValueDictionary` instead of an anonymous object.

```
Url.Action(
    nameof(this.MyMethod),
    new new RouteValueDictionary { { "SearchFilters.Firstname", viewModel.SearchFilters.Firstname }, { "SearchFilters.Surname", viewModel.SearchFilters.Surname } });
```